# How can I take out values from database that are related to the value the user picks?

Tags: php, mysql, database, find

I know a lot of HTML and CSS, but still learning PHP.  This is what I've come up with. I need the user to submit `code#` and it will find a value in the database.  This is my code:

```
$invitecode = $_GET['invitecode'];
$isattend = $_GET['attend'];
$isphone = $_GET['phone'];
$isemail = $_GET['email'];

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname FROM guests WHERE code = $code";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $lastname = $row["lastname"];
}}
```

now I can just `echo $firstname;`

what I need it to find other values that have the same `"relate"` field like the one I just pulled. So if I add relate to the information I'm getting.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, relate FROM guests WHERE code = $code";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
    $relate = $row["relate"];
}}
```

Then I launch another database search:

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, code FROM guests WHERE relate = $relate";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $first = $row["firstname"];
    $last = $row["lastname"];
    $code = $row["code"];
    echo " ?><input type="checkbox" name="add" value="<?php echo $code; ?>"><?php You are " . $first . " " . $last . "<br>";
}
}
```

I need the user to be able to select the values. That's why I'm also trying to add check marks by the new values. How could I make this work right?

Comment: Note that the above code has SQL injection vulnerabilities, and readers are advised not to copy it. Use parameter binding instead, which the mysqli library does indeed support. See the comments in Dave's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors.  That last block should be:

```
# This is a great way to get hacked.
# http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, code FROM guests WHERE relate = $relate";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
    // output data of each row
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $first = $row["firstname"];
        $last = $row["lastname"];
        $code = $row["code"];
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="add" value="<?php echo $code ?>"> You are "<?php echo $first ?>" "<?php echo $last ?><br>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Also, I suspect you really want that to be a radio and not a checkbox.  Checkboxes allow multiple selections.

Comment: I do need the checkboxes.  I tried with the corrections you gave above.  And it doesn't work.  Do I have to start a new connection before I do this? Or can I just use the current.

Comment: Thanks for the tip "http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php" never knew that. God Bless @dave